# My Filterable Adapter is finding results but not displaying

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

I have implemented `Filterable` in my `RecyclerView.Adapter<>` to search for specific locations by either their name or district. I log the result in every iteration in the `performFiltering()` method in the `Filter` like so where `filteredLocationList` is a class variable:

```
private class LocationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationsAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<Location> locationList;
    private List<Location> filteredLocationList;

    LocationsAdapter(List<Location> locationList) {
        this.locationList = locationList;
        this.filteredLocationList = locationList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_location_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Location location = locationList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(location.locName);
        holder.district.setText(location.locDistrict);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredLocationList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String searchTerm = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                Log.w(TAG, "search " + searchTerm);
                if (searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
                    filteredLocationList = locationList;
                } else {
                    List<Location> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Location location : locationList) {
                        if (location.locName.toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm)) {
                            Log.i("location search", location.locName);
                            filteredList.add(location);
                        }
                    }
                    filteredLocationList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults searchResults = new FilterResults();
                searchResults.values = filteredLocationList;
                return searchResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredLocationList = (ArrayList<Location>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, district;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            district = view.findViewById(R.id.district);
        }
    }
}
```

The Log statements show the Locations are being found but the List is not updating accordingly. What could be the cause of this.

Comment: Is your `Adapter` pulling its data from `filteredLocationList`, or `locationList`? Please post the complete class.

Comment: both Lists are class vars. I keep locationList incase search has not returned results.

Comment: added the adapter class @MikeM.

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder()`, you're pulling data from `locationList`, rather than `filteredLocationList`. You've got it right in `getItemCount()`, but even though the size of the list may change, the actual data for the listed items won't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After referring to [this](https://www.camposha.info/source/android-recyclerview-search-filter/) tutorial, I made some changes to the `getFilter()` and `publishResults()` methods which seemed to have done the trick. The search results' values and count were assigned after searching. In the publishResults the adapter was used
`getFilter()`:

```
searchResults.values = filteredLocationList;
searchResults.count = filteredLocationList.size();
```

`publishResults()`:

```
adapter.filteredLocationList = (ArrayList<Location>) results.values;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I used AndroidHive tutorial at first: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/